# Guaranteeing uniqueness in sorted data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm brand new to Cassandra and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to order my data. I'm trying to record messages from twitch.tv for each streamer. I want something like the following

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_data.twitch_chat_by_broadcaster_and_timestamp (
    broadcaster_id int,
    timestamp int,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY (broadcaster_id, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

While not an issue for a hobby project, how do you solve the problem of two messages being sent at the exact same time. I'm aware of `TimeUUID`, but I want the messages sorted by the timestamp of when they were sent, and it doesn't look like there are any official ways to create a `TimeUUID` other than `now()`.

I envision using this database for getting all messages in a given time range for a given stream. I realize I could add another `UUID` field to guarantee uniqueness, but then that would screw up my query since I have to specify an exact time.

What's the right way to order this data to allow efficient querying?

Comment: This warrants a couple questions. Is `broadcast_id` unique in your data? The reason I ask is if you are piling up data/records for the same broadcast ID, this will eventually become a hot/wide partition (i.e. any partition that is > 10/20MB of size is not a great candidate for a partition key). If you're new to C*, I'd encourage you to do [this](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) & [this](https://www.datastax.com/learn/data-modeling-by-example) browser-based free courses

Comment: Thanks for calling this out. I'll definitely take a look at those courses.

Comment: Cheers and hope you would find them helpful in building internet-scale super scalable applications with Cassandra®!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realize I could add another UUID field to guarantee uniqueness, but then that would screw up my query since I have to specify an exact time.

Not if you added it as the last clustering column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chat_data.twitch_chat_by_broadcaster_and_timestamp (
    broadcaster_id int,
    timestamp int,
    message_id uuid,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY (broadcaster_id, timestamp, message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC, message_id ASC);
```

This way, you could simply generate a new UUID at write-time. As long as you queried by the partition key of `broadcaster_id`, the data would still be sorted by (both) `timestamp`, with `message_id` added to ensure uniqueness.

As far as I can see it, the query for messages by `broadcaster_id` doesn't change:

```
> SELECT * FROM twitch_chat_by_broadcaster_and_timestamp WHERE broadcaster_id=68;

 broadcaster_id | timestamp     | message_id                           | message
----------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------
             68 | 1705328231991 | ac74c7ba-1813-4b75-b873-8817c6f89a55 |            End of stream.
             68 | 1705328230499 | 0e2116d5-887c-4433-b9cc-e5c13534902d |  Next stream coming soon.
             68 | 1705327984482 | 01c52a3a-c1c3-4db4-b8a8-6f9fe3111911 |        Incoming messages!
             68 | 1705327983581 | 7a3c2444-5746-4928-9e6a-0ebaac7fbec5 | Next stream starting soon
```

Comment: Thanks! I read that inequality operators could only be used on the last search parameter. I misunderstood that to mean I could only use > and < on the message_id. I didn't realize that if I didn't specify the message_Id in my query I could use them on the time stamp.